# Launching a Python script in a separate console window...from a python script

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, command-line-interface, python-multithreading

I have a python command-line tool that allows the user to select a variety of options, each a module.

One of the options is a standalone python script that doesn't share any I/O or state with the main program, but it runs continuously and would be blocking. I'd really like to launch it in a separate console window, where the user will be prompted for input and it will run until they manually exit.

I've tried several `subprocess` options thus far, but the farthest I've gotten is launching a new window that just...hangs.

Of course, I'd like to be as OS-agnostic as possible. I'm guessing the type of terminal emulator matters here, though, among other things. Should I looking at the multiprocessing module?

I welcome any advice that would help me get on the right track or point out any obvious (or perhaps not-so-obvious) flaws in my perspective. I'd like to adhere to the best-practice for this situation but am just not experienced enough. Thanks.

Edit: I got this to work by calling the actual submodule:

```
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"python3 -m name.of.module; exec bash\"'")
```

This works splendidly, but I get all this ugly output from Gnome inside of the main program that launched the second process:

```
# Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
# Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.
# _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation local (GLocalVfs) for ‘gio-vfs’
# posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested) 
# _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation dconf (DConfSettingsBackend) for ‘gsettings-backend’
# watch_fast: "/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
# unwatch_fast: "/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/" (active: 0, establishing: 1)
# watch_established: "/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/" (establishing: 0)
```

Using `--` in lieu of `-e` causes a child process error. I've also tested other subprocess calls with the `--` option and I still get some ugly output from Gnome. I can pipe stderr to /dev/null but I don't feel like this very clean.

Is this generally a sensible solution, or is this bad design (on my part, that is)?

Comment: I'd try `subprocess` (`Popen` or similar) with option `shell=True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thus far, I've gotten this to work on both Linux and Mac. It's ugly, though; I'd welcome a better answer, but haven't found one.

```
def open_new_window(module_name):
   if (operating_sys == "linux" or operating_sys == "linux2"):
      os.system(f"gnome-terminal -e 2>/dev/null 'bash -c \"python3 -m app.{module_name}; exec bash\"'")
   if (operating_sys == "darwin"):
      os.system(f"""osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
      do script "cd {root_path}; python3 -m app.{module_name}"
      end tell' """)
   else:
      print("[-] Your operating system does not support this utility.\n")
```

It works. Passing stdout to /dev/null on the linux option will get rid of the messy Gnome output. This method allows me to dynamically call modules that need to run in their own console window, detached from the main program. For running scripts that don't need to share state, it works just fine and manages to be *somewhat* cross-platform.

Still, I feel like there must be a more Pythonic way to do this.

Note: I've noticed on many related posts, the statement "in a new window" causes some confusion. "In a new window" here means the app literally opens a new shell window (unfortunately, *which* shell will need to be hardcoded for you) and starts the module as a standalone process (the main app does not keep track of it). For others using this solution, keep this in mind - this is certainly NOT a good way to do this if you need to manage I/O from main instance.